# Как правильно подключать библиотеку к проекту?

Tags: c++, c

Работаю с камерой, к ней идет SDK (http://www.jai.com/en/support/jai_sdk_and_control_tool) в виде *.lib* библиотеки и кучи файлов *.h* (230 штук), один из которых - главный (его подключаем, а он уже подключает остальные). Библиотека устанавливается в папку *ProgramFiles*. Для написания кода мне не обязательно её копировать в проект, я могу просто подключить главный хедер и *.lib*. Но в дальнейшем программа будет устанавливаться на другие компьютеры, и как она поймет откуда брать библиотеку? Пока что я скопировал библиотеку в проект, но 200 с лишним файлов в проекте чисто для одной библиотеки - мне кажется как-то не круто... Как лучше быть в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть две параллельные проблемы - правовая (требования авторов библиотеки к технологии распространения) и техническая. Правовая пока останется в стороне, тут нужно уточнять лицензию библиотеки.

Техническая:

- библиотека может компоноваться статически, тогда она уже встроена в ваш выполняемый файл, и ничего делать не надо.
- библиотека компонуется динамически, значит, все `dll` файлы стоит как минимум упаковать в инсталлятор и положить возле выполняемого при установке.

Что делать нежелательно и опасно:

- заставлять пользователя искать и скачивать библиотеку в интернете
- помещать библиотеку в папку, отличную от папки приложения, например, в папку `WINDOWS` или в папку `SYSTEM32`

Полезный инструмент для работы с библиотеками - [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Он позволяет найти все `dll`, от которых зависит данный `exe`

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ваш ответ.
Т.е. лучший варинат (в техническом плане) - это добавить эту библиотеку в мой проект? Даже если она большая (в плане количества файлов).

Comment: @JaroslavChernov исходники тащить не нужно, только dll.

Comment: Получается, в моем случае лучше её подключать динамически, через dll ? А если статически, через .lib - то придется тащить хедеры?

Comment: @JaroslavChernov к сожалению, я не экстрасенс. Я подозреваю, что эта библиотека и есть в виде DLL.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться.